# Suppose f is a smooth map from Rn to Rn, f∘f=f and f(Rn)⊂Rn. Proof that f(Rn) cannot be equal to W=W1∪W2 where W is connected and dimW1=k1≠k2= dimW2.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry

Suppose $f$ is a smooth map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f \circ f= f$ and $f(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Proof that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ cannot be equal to $W=W_1 \cup W_2$ where W is connected and dim$W_1 = k_1 \neq k_2 = $ dim$W_2$.

My attempt:

Suppose $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is connected and $f(\mathbb{R}^n) = W_1 \cup W_2$ where dim$W_1 \neq$ dim$W_2$. Then I want to show that there exist a tangent space of dimension $max\{$dim$W_1$,dim$W_2$$\}$ cause of the smoothnes of $f$ and came with a contradiction because the tangent space of maximum dimention is not defined on $W_{min_{dimW_i}(i)}$.

The problem is that I don't know how to show that the tangent space of maximum dimension exists.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you assuming that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ ? Otherwise what defininition of dimension are you using ?

Comment: I meant that dim$W_1 = k_1$ means that $W_1$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k_1}$ and is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k_1 - 1}$ . You cannot assume that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are submanifolds cause they aren't open in inducted topology ($W$ is connected, open and is a union of two sets. Cause $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorf, the sets can't be open).

Comment: Try to show that $W$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$, this will prove your result

Comment: I guess $W_i$ should be non-empty, closed in $\Bbb R^n$ and disjoint, otherwise the identity map provides a counterexample.